# How to organize my python modules and packages

Tags: pip, python-module

So I have written a module A and a dedicated test-file. This module can be used alone, but I wrote it to be used as a "base" for a second module I wrote. This second module absolutely needs the first one, and also has it's own test-file.
Finaly, I wrote a third module that is based on the first two modules. In other words :

- module A, can be used without B or C.
- module B needs module A, and can be used without C
- module C needs module B (and so also A)

My question is how do treat all these modules ? For example, should I make each module a package, and then import A in B, and B in C ? Or should I put them all in a single package ? Also, what do I do of all the test files (put them next to the module, or all in a single test-folder) ?

As of today, I am treating each one as a package, but it seems a bit heavy to have to install A and B for using C:

```
+ moduleA
    - moduleA.py
    - test_moduleA.py
+ moduleB
    - moduleB.py
    - test_moduleB.py
+ moduleC
    - moduleC.py
    - test_moduleC.py
```

So I was thinking about merging all like this :

```
+ moduleC
    - moduleA.py
    - moduleB.py
    - moduleC.py
    + tests
        - test_moduleA.py
        - test_moduleB.py
        - test_moduleC.py
```

Is that the pythonic way to wrap my module C (and all its components) ? Or should I nest the modules in subpackages (moduleC.moduleB.moduleA) ?

The goal of all this is to export to github-like platform, and eventually pip.

Comment: I don't understand *can be used alone* part. Module B needs module A but could work without it? Module C needs module B but could work without it?

Comment: Yeah sorry I realized afterward it wasn’t very clear. « B can be used alone » means one could want to use B without C (as well as one could use A without B). But enventually, I just want all A, B and C in one package. So should they all be in the same folder (package level), or in cascading sub-folder (sub-packages)..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modules seem to be independent so they should be developed separately: separate development directories, separate git repositories.

For proper installation the modules should declare dependencies: B depends on A and C directly depends on B and indirectly (transitively via B) depends on A. Such dependencies should be declared in `setup.py`:

In B:

```
setup(
    …
    install_requires=[A]
    …
)
```

In C:

```
setup(
    …
    install_requires=[B]
    …
)
```

No need to declare dependency on A as B when being installed brings A with it.

This way when installing `pip install A` A will be installed alone;
when installing `pip install B` B will be installed with A;
when installing `pip install C` C will be installed with both A and B.

Comment: All right thanks, I’ll keep it this way then. Now, for better understanding, what about if module A for eg is super simple and only consist in a class or two and few functions, should it be included in B (making modules A and B in a package B) ? I’m still not sure about a functionanlity should be a submodule or a stand alone package (eg: numpy arrays could be in a stand alone base package, and all the functionnalities that extend it could be in another package (that would require the arrays package - like, arrays can be used « alone », and consist in the core of the high level package)

Comment: The question is too generic so the answer is so: do whatever works for you.